# Otros Logviewer – Pattern for New Line

Tags: otroslogviewer

I tried to view logs for my application through Ostro log viewer, It seems that I am doing wrong with Ostro pattern.

> Log4j property is :
>   log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%t ** %p **%n%d, (%F:%L)%n%m%n

Equivalent Ostro log viewer pattern :

```
pattern=THREAD ** LEVEL **NEWLINE TIMESTAMP, (FILE:LINE) NEWLINE MESSAGE
```

I tried with above pattern but When I do “Test parser”, it is showing  - 0 events parsed, I am not sure NEWLINE is the right pattern for %n.

Please Help me out what I am doing wrong with above pattern.

Comment: Finally I check out the code from the repository and analyse the code to identify the behaviour.
There is no any way to handle New Line in the Log entry using Otros pattern. The only solution would be modify the Ostros code and generate the new binaries.

Comment: have you tried log4j-native? https://github.com/otros-systems/otroslogviewer/wiki/Log4jPatternLayout#the-log4j-native-parser